# Local Apache Server Redirects

Tags: php, windows, apache

I have a local virtual host for my main site, local.mysite.com.  I also have other virtual hosts for other projects I am working on.  For instance, local.mygame.com.  For some reason, after adding in the virtual host information and adding the string to my hosts file, whenever I access local.mygame.com, or local.phpmyadmin.com, it redirects to local.mysite.com everytime.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.mysite.com
    ServerAlias local.mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /mysite/content

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName local.mygame.com

    DocumentRoot /www/mygame
    LogLevel debug

</VirtualHost>
```

Hosts file contains:

```
127.0.0.1 local.mysite.com
127.0.0.1 local.mygame.com
```

It does a 302 redirect from local.mygame.com to local.mysite.com

Comment: Any `RewriteRule`s? Did you try to remove that `ServerAlias`? I does not do much since the alias is the same as `ServerName`. Did you check that your host is correctly spelled? If nothing match you will end up in the first host specified in the file (Used as default).

Comment: None of that is the problem, see comment below

Comment: If you find an answer you could answer, and accept your own answer. For future readers. Also if you find more issues update your question with relevant things if you want others to answer the "updated" question. :)

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to access over SSL, in which case you need similar Vhost configurations for port 443 (i.e. `<VirtualHost *:443>...</VirtualHost>`)

Comment: didn't work.  could it have something to do with the certificate? I just copied it from another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "AllowOverride none" in case a .htaccess file is overriding your settings here

Comment: not the problem, I removed ssl conf and it worked, so it's something in my httpd-ssl.conf file

Comment: Now it is not redirecting, but I get "Webpage is not available"